# jQuery's .change() may not be firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, onchange

I am trying to insert a value into the Database when the value of a Textbox is changed by the User. I have checked the backend code (C#) on its own, without the jQuery and have confirmed that it is working, which leads me to believe that the problem is that the jQuery `.change()` event is not being fired.

I've seen many of the same questions, though none of the solutions seem relevant. How can I get this working?

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.qty').change(function () {
            $.post('/InlineEditing.cshtml', { qty: $(this).val(), id: $(this).attr('id') },
                function (data) {
                    alert(data.trim());
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="qty" id="1" value="0" />
```

Comment: Are you looking to post to your server when the text changes (i.e. every key typed, or a paste event on the textbox etc.) OR when the user presses enter/tab on the textbox (`.change()` fires when this happens)

Comment: .change() fires only after textbox loses focus. Is this what you need or do you want it to fire whenever you press a button? In that case use .keyup() instead

Comment: @techfoobar and gintas; I did not know that .change() fired only when the element loses focus (I'm new to jQuery) - *however*, I did also try clicking away from the input element just in-case that's how it worked, and it still didn't get fired.

Comment: Why did you add asp.net mvc as a tag to this question? This has absolutely nothing to do with MVC. I am working with ASP.NET Web Pages framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reliably handle text changes, use zurb's **textchanged** event instead. This works for keystrokes, paste operations, cut operations etc.

http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

Check this **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JnCXG/

**Code:**

```
$('#foo').bind('textchange', function (event, previousText) {   
    console.log('Text changed');
});
```

Comment: Wow nice tip! Wasn't aware of this lib.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several aspects to this problem:

- If you want to update server status on every keypress you could listen to `keypress` event instead.
- Also note you possibly should point your HTTP command into a URL that accepts POST 
  commands, not into the rendered HTML.
- `alert` is horribly insufficient for debugging what happens in your script. Consider using a JavaScript debugger like Firebug to find out what really gets sent to the server.

For an example, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dfH7y/3/ (you need to open JavaScript console to see `console.log` output)

Answer (score 0):

You can write function on `Keyup` or `onblur` event instead of change. Change event is suitable in select box.